# Where is joomla Virtuemart $addtocart variable defined

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Where is joomla Virtuemart `$addtocart` variable defined?
This variable shows add to cart button. I need to add some class on this button.SoI need to know where this variable is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the add to cart in **components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\templates\product_details\includes\addtocart_form.tpl.php**